# ClamAV shows errors found, but how to find out what they are?

Tags: anti-virus, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, clamav

Amazon includes `clamav-0.98.4` in its AMI [version 2014.09.1](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.09-release-notes/#New_packages) so I installed it and gave it a try on one of my EC2 instances.

After updating the definitions with [`freshclam`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/freshclam), I've performed a scan with [`ClamAV`](http://www.clamav.net/doc/install.html) using this command:

```
clamscan / -ir \
    --exclude-dir=^/sys \
    --exclude-dir=^/dev \
    --exclude-dir=^/proc \
    --scan-mail=yes
```

After completion, this is the output:

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 3685614
Engine version: 0.98.4
Scanned directories: 23438
Scanned files: 223072
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 2
Data scanned: 6812.04 MB
Data read: 43300.34 MB (ratio 0.16:1)
Time: 2333.526 sec (38 m 53 s)
```

It shows I have **0 infected files**, but **2 errors**. I'd like to see these errors, but they aren't present in the output.

I started reading the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clamscan) and tried running the command again, but now with the `--verbose` option added to it. The output was exactly the same, except it was preceded by thousands of lines like this:

```
Scanning /usr/bin/symlinks
Scanning /usr/bin/package-cleanup
Scanning /usr/bin/unzipsfx
Scanning /usr/bin/gpg-agent
```

And so on.

After this I tried adding the `--log=/var/log/clamscan.log` option, to make `clamscan` write to a log file. Opening this file after it had finished running just showed me the same as the output on the command line.

I can't seem to find out what these errors it has found exactly are. Is there any way to figure this out? Or better yet, have `clamscan` include this in the log file?

Comment: I have the same problem @ClamAV, can't find any way to produce a useful report...